# Can't send reset password message in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, email, authentication, passwords, reset

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="username@gmail.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'username@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Name'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('username'),
'password' => env('password'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'username' => env('username')
'password' => env('password')
```

Should be:

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME')
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD')
```